# How to give permission for the custom users to allow to access plugin configuration from backend in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have written a plugin. Their admin can access it and do the plugin configuration. Now I need to give this permission for the particular users I created to access and configure the plugin.

Problem is I don't need them to access other configurations in back-end such as page creation, user creation, plugin installation and etc.

I have added the plugin to the setting menu in wordpress backend.

So how to set permission from plugin code to allow configuration from back-end only for my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to place your plugin menu under Tools with [`add_management_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_management_page) and set the [`capability`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_management_page#Parameters) argument to one that matches the desired [user role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).